# Windows phone dropdownlist choose options not showing current selected option

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, html-select

I am working on windows phone 8.1 universal app using cordova. I am getting very weird issue while working with dropdownlist.

When tap on dropdownlist it open Choose An Item screen where we can select item. But this screen always shows options from start not from selected option.

For example i have year dropdownlist start option from 2001 to 2050. And i have selected year 2025 so whenever i open dropdownlist it always shows from 2001 not from 2025.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the selected option in the Local settings and read it when you open the "Choose an item" screen. Something like this:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Year"] = "2002";
```

Comment: i am not getting. how it is related to local setting? my problem is i am not getting current selection in choose item screen.

Comment: You said that you are not getting the selected item. This looks that there is no way for the code to remember your last selected option and therefore it is picking the default/first value. How are you storing the selected option, and how are you picking that value? Can you share some code to investigate the issue?

Comment: I have not any problem in selection and getting selected option. it is working as it is normal dropdown. Problem with Choose an item screen. In that screen i am not getting that item as selected. i mean that item is present but not shows as selected.